# Can i still connect to raspberry pi after use it for wifi extender?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I am going to make wifi extender with my raspberry pi 4 (with ethernet cable), but recently my rasp is running some work on it and i access it via ssh and ip address. So after i make that function to my rasp, can i access to rasp again (if yes, will it change ip or no) ? Or it will turning to an extender only?

P/s: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said exactly how you intend to do this, but presuming it is a reasonably normal methodology using Raspbian/RPiOS or another general purpose OS then yes, you will be able to log in via SSH and use it normally.  You could even connect a screen and keyboard and run a GUI on it.

I haven't used a Pi as a router/AP/hostspot with more than a couple of clients, but I think the bandwidth will be much more of a restriction than the processing power needed to work packets (which linux should be pretty adept at), meaning even when throughput is at a maximum the system should remain responsive for other activities.  A multi-core model is obvious preferable for this.

Comment: I run a 3B+ as a WiFi to Ethernet bridge (to keep the same IP range on the WiFi as the Ethernet) and fine response is fine to do other tasks as long as you keep the user count to around 5 at max and limit streaming.  Bandwidth suffers first - CPU use is low.